# jQuery .click() doesn´t work after replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a website and trying to translate using jQuery, so I don't have to refresh the whole page, I have this html markup:

```
<nav class="menu">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="find_us"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul> 
</nav>
```

Using jQuery on the About Us link I do this:

```
        //SHOW MAP
    $('.find_us a').click(function () {
        $('#google_map').fadeIn();
    });
```

And with this code I close the map window:

```
       //CLOSE MAP
       $(".home a").click(function () {
           $('#google_map').fadeOut();
        });
```

The problem begins when I do click on the link to change the language:

```
<a class="spanish" href="#"><img src="images/flags/es.gif" alt="ES" /></a>
    //ES
    $( ".spanish" ).click(function() {
        $('.home a').replaceWith('<a href="#">Inicio</a>'),
        $('.find_us a').replaceWith('<a href="#">Acerca De</a>');
    });
```

All jQuery code inside the anonymous jQuery function:

```
$(function(){/*jQuery code*/});
```

From this point I'm not able to show or close the map again once I call the `replaceWith()` method, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically three different solutions.

You can replace the text in the links instead of the links themselves:

```
$( ".spanish" ).click(function() {
    $('.home a').text('Inicio'),
    $('.find_us a').text('Acerca De');
});
```

You can rebind the events after replacing the elements.

You can bind a delegate on a parent element, so that replacing the element doesn't remove the event binding:

```
$('.find_us').on('click', 'a', function () {
    $('#google_map').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

event delegation

```
$('.find_us').on('click', 'a', function () {
    $('#google_map').fadeIn();
});
$('.home').on('click', 'a', function () {
    $('#google_map').fadeOut();
});
```

or just change the text, not the `a` element

```
//ES
$( ".spanish" ).click(function() {
    $('.home a').text('Inicio'),
    $('.find_us a').text('Acerca De');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of click:

```
$('.find_us a').on('click', function () {    
   $('#google_map').fadeIn();
});
$(".home a").on("click",function () {
   $('#google_map').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem. This is just another way to bind the click event. I think binding a delegate on parent element as @Guffa said is the best way. Another solution (not the best) is to do a live binding `$(document).on('click', '.find_us a', function () {     $('#google_map').fadeIn();});`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are binding click event on `a` elements that are removed then to append new ones. The new `a` elements does not have click event binded to them.

Answer (score 0):

When you use replaceWith, it's destroying the element that has the event attached to it. You could add the event back to it every time you replace it, or you could attach the event to all 'a' descendant elements, like this:

```
$('.find_us').on("click", "a", function () {
    $('#google_map').fadeIn();
});

$(".home").on("click", "a", function () {
    $('#google_map').fadeOut();
});
```